# cakephp isAuthorized Function

Tags: cakephp

In the cakephp 2 book -> Authorization example -> (who’s allowed to access what).

[Actual Link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html)

The function `isAuthorized($user)` is declared but never called. How that it works?

ThAnKs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add also in `public $components`

```
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'authorize' => array('Controller') // Added this line
    )
);
```

And `isAuthorized()` is only called after the user logs in.